# drupal 7 presist data in form_state with managed_file

Tags: forms, file-upload, drupal-7

I use D7 managed File.

If i have form error than the form lost file info, i know that is there an error a have to reupload the files.

But in the form validator i have the file save in the db so i have the FId of the file (from file_load)

If I can presist value in form state i can load the file from db in form submit and make it presistent.

in form:

```
$form['fileUpload'] = array(
        '#id'                => 'fileUploadId',
        //'#type'  => 'file',
        '#title' => t('upload a file: '),
        '#size'              => 22,
        '#type'              => 'managed_file',
        '#description'       => t('upload file: docx doc pdf'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
        '#upload_validators' => array(
            'file_validate_extensions' => array('docx doc pdf'),
            // Pass the maximum file size in bytes
            'file_validate_size' => array(4*1024*1024),
        ),            
      );
```

i tried:

1. I pass the &$form_state by reference in form validator , submit, and form

   $form_state['values']['FileInfo'] =  $form_state['values']['fileUpload'];

If there is form error form_state lost this value

1. I pass the &$form_state by reference in form validator , submit, and form

   $file = file_load($form_state['values']['fileUpload']);

   $form_state['values']['FileInfo'] = $form->fid;
2. form_set_value($element, $value, &$form_state) for persist form_state data

But it's bit tricky to use.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

1. i create a hidden field in the form :

   ```
           $form['infoFile'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => '');
   ```
2. in the form validator:

   ```
           $file = file_load($form_state['values']['candidateCvUpload']);
           $form['infoFile']['#parents'] = array('infoFile');
           form_set_value($form['infoFile'], $file->fid, $form_state);
   ```
3. submit

   ```
           $file->status   = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
           $file = file_save($file);
   ```